# Layer generation in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a fairly complex picture with many overlapping areas. Is there a way to pass each `\draw` snippet to a layer specified in the options? Or even better, based on its axis position?

I know of the `backgrounds` library but only offers two layers. In the [manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) section 108.3 (pg. 1080) `pgfonlayer` is introduced. That would meet my needs but it requires encapsulating each command (or block of commands) with a `begin{pgfonlayer}{<layer>}…\end{pgfonlayer}` so that is cumbersome and reduces readibility. I want something like `\draw[layer=<layer>]`, in the way the `backgrounds` library does. How would I go about achieving that?

---

A small MWE to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backlayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backlayer2}
\pgfdeclarelayer{frontlayer}
\pgfsetlayers{backlayer,backlayer2,main,frontlayer}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red] (1,1) rectangle (3,3);
\fill[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\fill[green] (0,0) circle (1.5);
\end{scope}
%with layers
\begin{pgfonlayer}{frontlayer}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{backlayer}
\fill[red] (1,1) rectangle (3,3);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
\fill[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{backlayer2}
\fill[green] (0,0) circle (1.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the order change even though the code is still ordered in the same way.

Comment: The question is interesting but could you add a MWE?

Comment: You can copy the code from the library to create as many layers as you wish and then use them in the same way as the pre-defined one. However, you have to define all the layers you need and set the hierarchy so that Ti*k*Z knows what to draw first.

Comment: `the code is still ordered in the same way` but on different ordered layers.

Comment: @Symbol1 Very nice, I did not find it myself. I will close this question.